# Lavalamp Menu - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, lavalamp

I was searching for Lavalamp menu solution and I found this little script. I am not sure if that's the best one around but looks nice and can be easily modified.

However it contain one error in console and I don't like errors so any help would be appreciated.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null
```

[Lavalamp Menu Original Source](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/creating-a-fancy-menu-using-css3-and-jquery/)

[Lavalamp Menu Fix JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/4CU4H/)

You can go to that JS Fiddle fix and see in console when going through the menu it will show that property error.

I don't know how to resolve this, so any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it like so inside the 'mouseleave' branch:

```
        if ($this.siblings('li.active').offset()) {
            left = $this.siblings('li.active').offset().left - ($this.closest('.' + lavalamp).offset().left);
            width = $this.siblings('li.active').width();

            $this.closest('ul').next('div.floatr').css({
                "width": width + "px",
                "left": left + "px"

            });
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to line 35 of the javascript section of the fiddle.

`$this.siblings('li.active')`

Does not return anything, which is why the Chrome debugger returns the error `Cannot read property 'left' of null`